# Is it possible to click this button with .click()?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to figure out a way to click this with JavaScript's `.click()`

```
<input type="button" class="button" value="Test">
```

Is there a way to do that with the given attributes or do I need to add more (Id or Name) so I can use `getElementby`?

Comment: What is the button doing? Did you attach any event handler? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could do it with getElementsByTagName("input") and look for items with an attribute type of button-- but you're better off getting it with an id attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Going off the top of my head:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
   if ((i.type == 'button') && (i.className == 'button') && (i.value == 'Test')) {
       i.click();
       break;
   }
}
```

It'd definitely be easier to put an ID onto the button, so you can simply have/do:

```
<input id="mybutton" class=... ...>

document.getElementById('mybutton').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll save yourself a lot of hastle if you add an `id` attribute to your HTML.

Then you can simply do:

```
document.getElementById('mybutton').click();
```

and with a null check:

```
var element = document.getElementById('mybutton');

if(element != null)
{
    element.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to add an id. One alternative would be to get all the DOM elements, then search through them until you found one with the exact values, but that's a lot of unnecessary work.

Answer (score 0):

You can surely retrieve the element by using existing attributes but this depends on which other buttons you have in your form. **Having a specified `id` is always a good idea in these situations**.

Even using **jQuery** with `$("#yourid").click()` is always a good idea..

Answer (score -2):

```
`<input type="button" class="button" value="Test" id="btnTest">`
`<input type="button" class="button" value="Test" id="clickTest" onclick="myClick()">`
function myClick()
{

btnTest.click();
}
```

Comment: -1 for not answering the question - author not looking for a way to add a click handler, he's looking for a way to fire a click event.